# How to align images (with CSS) to a block of text on different screen widths?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, grid

Suppose we have block of text in the middle of the website, and two images - one to the left of the image, and one to the right of it.

However, on a device with smaller width, I want to have those 2 images under the text in a row. It seems simple but I didn't manage to come with an answer to that.

**How it looks on a narrow screen:**

[image: How it looks on a narrow screen]

**How it looks on a wide screen:**

[image: How it looks on a wide screen]

I tried using different media queries but I only managed to put all items in a column, which I don't want to do.

Comment: don't forget to mark as resolved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using css grids
You have to use `@media only screen and (max-width: {value}px)` to add css properties for screens smaller than `value` pixels

I think this is what you want :

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  justify-self: center;
}

.text{
  text-align: center;
}

.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 2fr auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .text{
    grid-column : 1/4;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  
  .img1{
    grid-column : 1;
    grid-row : 2;
  }
  
  .img1{
    grid-column : 3;
    grid-row : 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class='img1' src=""/>
  <div class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id lacus rutrum, auctor ligula imperdiet, porttitor ipsum. Proin a dolor quis felis pretium convallis. Cras nec accumsan neque. Vivamus nec venenatis lacus. Cras elementum id lorem sit amet iaculis. Pellentesque rhoncus a lorem a congue. Aenean suscipit est et est lacinia interdum. Pellentesque mattis odio scelerisque, sagittis lacus in, convallis leo.</div>
  <img class='img2' src=""/>
</div>
```

You could also change the `grid-template-columns` property for smaller screens to have a better result

Comment: sorry, I made a few changes but now it should be working

Comment: It works, thanks! Although on the website I noticed such behavior there was flexbox used I think, but I couldn't find how it works in the developer tools. Here's the website: https://www.nowehoryzonty.pl/vod-film.s?id=13015 - I'm talking about the movie description and those 2 images.

Comment: you could probably use flexboxes as well but in my opinion grids are more adapted in this case

Comment: On that website the images were in one span tag and the text in the other one and I can't really figure out how it's done.

Comment: Otherwise it's hard to control those images if the text and images are in the same div, not wrapped by anything